# Unable to merge dex after adding dependencies

Tags: android, android-multidex

I am getting the error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForPaidFreeDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>      com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

After adding the following two dependencies:

```
implementation 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
```

Here are all of my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
// in app billing
compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
compile 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:1.2.1'
//
compile 'com.github.simbiose:Encryption:2.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'me.everything:providers-android:1.0.1'
//dateTime Picker
implementation 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
//Date Time
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
compile 'com.github.danysantiago:sendgrid-android:1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
//Logging
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
//Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
//Rx
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.8'

//butterknife
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1-rc1'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.1-rc1'
testCompile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.7-beta'
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.1-rc1'
testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

My default config:

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.webnation.text2email"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

I have upgraded the memory, added multiDexEnabled, added the support library for multi-dex.

Interesting, I had to add

```
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
```

in order to get it to the multidex error.

I can't seem to find a solution.

Detailed error:

> Error:07:48:24.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   07:48:24.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   07:48:24.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   07:48:24.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
>   07:48:24.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForPaidFreeDebug'.
>   07:48:24.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/kristywelsh/Dropbox/SMS2Email1/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/paidFree/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/kristywelsh/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/31fbbff1ddbf98f3aa7377c94d33b0447c646b6e/httpcore-4.3.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [httpcore-4.3.2.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]))
>   07:48:24.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   07:48:24.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
>   07:48:24.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
>   07:48:24.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   07:48:24.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   07:48:24.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
>   07:48:24.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 34s

Comment: Examine your Gradle console. There should be more details in there of exactly what went wrong. This is just the end message.

Comment: @CommonsWare added detailed error.

Comment: maybe this is not the point but a thing: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2' seem to be repeated under (compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Duplicate zip entry [httpcore-4.3.2.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]
```

You are picking up two copies of this Java class, from sources that Gradle is not netting out in its dependency resolution process.

One possibility is that one of your new dependencies has a transitive dependency on Apache HttpCore, but that `libs/droidText.0.2.jar` or one of your other dependencies has its own copy of `org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe`.

Android Studio has the "External Libraries" portion of the project tree, if you are in the Project view (rather than the default Android view):

[image: Android Studio External Libraries tree]

The only way that I know of to track this down is to start sifting through your libraries and try to identify the 2+ that have `org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe`. Then, try to figure out how to stop using one of those. The libraries that have this class may be through transitive dependencies, and so you would also need to identify where those transitive dependencies came from. This will be painful, which is why that I am hoping that [newer versions of Android Studio will be more helpful here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69958400).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I will sift down through the dependencies.

Comment: I did indeed find the duplicate, as well as one other.  It had nothing to do with my new dependencies, but the fact that my old gradle plugin allowed them before upgrading to 3.0.  However, your answer led the way to my solving the problem.

Comment: @KristyWelsh: "but the fact that my old gradle plugin allowed them before upgrading to 3.0" -- yes, the new one seems to complain in cases where the old one did not. Not sure why. Glad to hear that it is working for you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application class..

```
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
      super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "hi"));
      MultiDex.install(this);
 }
```

like :-

> also extend the MultiDexApplication by your Application class

```
public class MyApplication  extends MultiDexApplication {



      @Override
      protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
           super.attachBaseContext(base);
           MultiDex.install(this);
}


     @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     }


}
```

**Edit:- As you are using targetSdkVersion <=23 you need to install it manually.,.**
and dont forget to add `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` to your application tag in the manifest.xml.. like this :-

```html
<application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
```

Comment: I can't seem to find LocaleHelper.  Is this a class in your app?

Comment: let me edit.. sorry..just use the `attachBaseContext` method @KristyWelsh

Comment: yes..i had the same problem..i used this to solve it.. @KristyWelsh

Comment: just go to *manifest.xml - > then from application tag -> go to .YourApplication - > then extend it and install it manually.. this is because.. you are using targetSdkVersion 19*]

Comment: Even changing the min version and targetSDK version did not help.

Comment: did you try `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` instead of `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` @KristyWelsh

Comment: I'm using compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'.  And I changed my target version and min version to 21.

Comment: after adding these did you try invalidating cache and restart ?? @Kristy Welsh