# Unable to Merge Dex - Android Studio 3.0.1 DexArchiveMergerException

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

I started getting the below error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I tried to reset my backup when it was working but the same problem

I tried all the solution such as

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

cleaning and rebuilding the project, but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

App file

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "auto"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.2'
    grpcVersion = '1.4.0'
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//appcompat libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'

//butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

//retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.scottyab:aes-crypto:0.0.4'
//circleimageview
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
//ZXing for barCode reader
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
//gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
//recyclerview and cardview
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
//play-services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'




    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

}
```

Project file

```html
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I had looked at many other questions and answers on here but cannot seem to find a solution that will rectify the problem :(

Comment: Examine your Gradle console. There should be more details in there of exactly what went wrong. This is just the end message. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48990598/115145) for an example.

Comment: I'm just getting the error message DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49026135/8568479) to the similar question. Also replace deprecated `compile` by `implementation` in your gradle file

Comment: I already tried this solution but nothing change

Comment: I've noticed that you declare supportLibraryVersion, which is not used anywhere. For example you can replace 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2' by 'com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}' and do so for all `com.android.support` libraries. In your question there are inconsistent different versions of support library.

Comment: I know that but I do it to make sure the problem is not from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved after try all the solutions on stackoverflow, try to do the following steps in its order

1. Replace all compile with implementation
2. Make all supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.2'
3. Change

> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'

to

> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'

4. Remove all the unused library
5. Delete the .gradle folder inside your project
6. Remove build folders and the gradle cache
7. file -> invalidate caches/restart
8. Build > Clean Project
9. Add

> dependencies { implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'}

9. Add

> android {
>       defaultConfig {
>           multiDexEnabled true
>           }
>   }

9. Async project

And finally this is my App file

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.2'

}
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'


//constraint
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//butterknife
    implementation  'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
//avi:library
    implementation  'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

//circleimageview
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

//retrofit2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.0.2'


//recyclerview and cardview
    implementation  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'


//ZXing for barCode reader
    implementation  'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation  'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'

//play-services
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'

//gson
    implementation  'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
//statusbarutil
    implementation  'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.4.0'
//glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
//multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

ِِActually I didn't understand the real reason about it and why that happened suddenly

So if anyone know that please tell me with full details

I hope this will help you

Comment: for me It happened because of pagging library. They have moved some classes from library to native recylerview-v7 package, So I got the same exception , I had to update support libs version to `27.1.0`(latest) and also pagging library to `alpha6`

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me after couple of hours wasting time

just do this

> **Implementation** >>> **annotationProcessor**

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Do you mean just to replace word `Implementation` with `annotationProcessor` allover in app build gradle?

Comment: what is this? How is this an answer?